# Extract <div title="xpto"> element with BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract all `<div title="some different text here">` elements but I couldn't find a way.

There are some of them spread over the HTML structure but it seems that I need to fill the `title` attribute with the right value of text, but they are all different.

What I am trying:

```
container_indicators = today_container.find_all('div', {'title'})
```

But it didn't work out.

I'm working with beautiful soup + python.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
container_indicators = today_container.find_all('div', attrs={'title': True})
```

---

Or:

```
container_indicators = today_container.select('div[title]')
```